# ContentView V/S SuperView in iOS?

Tags: ios, view

Well I am newbie, to iOS Application Development. I am reading through some reference to develop my application. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIVisualEffectView/contentView

I am familiar with the concept of Super View and Sub View from View Hierarchy with iOS. But I am confused with the term "ContentView" of the view. Does it mean the view itself or SuperView of that view ?

Please describe how to know what is contentView of the view ?

Comment: Content view is basically area of your content. If your content will increase then it will automatically increase and vice versa. In a simple language it is just a simple view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, contentView usually means the main/major view inside something.

In this context it means the view to which effect can be added which is synonym to contentView.

In UIScrollView, the word content refers to the main scrollable view in it. (just so you understand)